# The frame of a \framebox disappears in pdfpages

Tags: pdfpages

I am trying to put the word "hello" on every page of a pdf file using `pdfpages`. The following code works, but the frame around "hello" disappears. I tried it on a one blank page pdf file (called "letter.pdf" in the same directory). The first page has an unboxed "hello", but the next page (output in an ordinary way, without the pdfpages callback) works just fine.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
  \usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
  % page 1 (no frame around hello)
  \newcommand{\eachpage}{\framebox[1in][l]{hello}}
  \includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand={\eachpage}]{letter.pdf}
  % page 2 (frame works)
  \framebox[1in][l]{hello}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The package `pdfpages` *always* draws a frame around the included page; but the default is not showing it, which is obtained by setting `\fboxrule` to zero. Since the addition of `pagecommands` happens during PDF inclusion, a `\framebox` will inherit this setting. Note that `pdfpages` also sets `\fboxsep` to zero.

Solution:

```
\newlength{\defaultfboxrule}
\newlength{\defaultfboxsep}
\AtBeginDocument{% Remember the values
  \setlength{\defaultfboxrule}{\fboxrule}%
  \setlength{\defaultfboxsep}{\fboxsep}%
}
\newcommand{\normalfboxes}{%
  \setlength{\fboxrule}{\defaultfboxrule}%
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{\defaultfboxsep}%
}

\newcommand{\eachpage}{%
  \begingroup\normalfboxes
  \framebox[1in][l]{hello}%
  \endgroup
}
```